# How to check if two java script variables differ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this web grid in my view:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
<div id="gridContent">

    <button type="button" id="createNewPredefinedView" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">@Html.Localize("createNew")</button>

    @grid.GetHtml(
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns:

    grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("PredefID", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">@item.PredefineViewID </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode">@item.PredefineViewID</label> </text>, style: "col1Width"),


        grid.Column("", format: @<text>
        <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/edit.png" />
        <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/delete.png" />
        <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/Sensor.png" />
        <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" src="~/Images/save.png" />
        <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" src="~/Images/cancel.png" />
        </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false),



        grid.Column("AmountOfSensors", @Html.Localize("amountOfSensors").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  @item.SensorNo </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode"> @item.SensorNo </label> </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false)
     ))
</div>
```

And using this java script **I want to check if var sensorNumber is greater than zero, but since these are strings, I just want to see that it is everything BUT the string "0"**

```
$(".delete-table").on("click", function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    var sensorNumber = tr.find("#AmountOfSensors").html();
    var zero = "0"
    if ($(sensorNumber).val() !=  $(zero)) {
        alert("can't delete");
    }
    else { 
        //my delete code code goes here
    }
)};
```

But this way, my sensorNumber can contain the value "0".... and it will go to fulfill the if clause, the other values go to the if as well which is good, but I just want it to go to the else clause if it is a "0" and nothing else. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you wrap your 'zero' into jquery? Just check `$(sensorNumber).val() != "0"`

Comment: That's not the proper use of jQuery. Even without it, I'd still **strongly recommend** against comparing strings this way. Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to extract a number. And use identity `!==` rather than equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(zero)` in your code means `$("0")` selector so it doesn't make sense to compare with `$(zero)`. Moreover, since you have this syntax

```
var sensorNumber = tr.find("#AmountOfSensors").html();
```

then `sensorNumber` is actually the variable that you want to compare with `"0"`, so you don't need to use `$(sensorNumber).val()`. Assuming that `sensorNumber` always contains an integer, set `zero` as an integer and use `parseInt` function to make sure you're comparing two integers as below

```
var zero = 0;
if (parseInt(sensorNumber) != parseInt(zero))
```

or don't use `zero` variable at all

```
if (parseInt(sensorNumber) != parseInt(0))
```

Comment: I just tried 
    if ($(sensorNumber).val() != "0")
and it still fulfills the if function and doesnt go to else as it should when sensorNumber is "0"

Comment: What's the value of `sensorNumber`? Can you try to add `alert(sensorNumber);` before the `if` block?

Comment: when i add alert(sensorNumber) before the if block I get exactly the number that is written in the selected row

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. See the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: It works now, but only when i take out the "", so now its if(sensorNumber != 0) and it does what it is supposed to, I was convinced that all values inside of tags are strings, regardless if the model is an int like it is in my case.

Comment: Not sure how it's possible as `sensorNumber` is always a string in my testing. I've updated my answer to make sure the `if` block always compares two integers.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that I get my sensorNumber from the database where it is designed as an int?

Comment: Yes I guess so. Anyway the updated answer should work whether `sensorNumber` is a string or an integer, as long as it can be parsed to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing strings or numbers in JavaScript you don't need to wrap them into jQuery function. Just do a simple `==` check.

```
if ($(sensorNumber).val() !=  zero) {
   alert("can't delete");
}
```